# How to determine sign of second derivative from contour plot?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am working on a practice problem for my Calculus 3 course. I am given a contour plot and one of the questions is to determine the sign of the second derivative with respect to $x$ at $(3,2)$: $f_{xx}(3,2)$.

I have no clue how to determine this?  Could someone please explain the process of how to figure this out merely from a graph? Thanks.

Contour Plot:

[image: Contour]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stand yourself at the point $(3,2)$ in the contour plot and start walking parallel to the $x$-axis in the positive direction. First, we see that the $f(x,2)$ is increasing when we increase $x$ which indicates that $f_x(3,2)>0$. But we can even go a step further. Because not only does it increase but it increase faster and faster (in other words, the surface is getting steeper and steeper). This indicates that $f_{xx}(3,2)>0$.

Comment: Okay, I get why f_x(3,2) is positive, but I'm still kinda lost on how you're able to tell that f_xx(3,2) is positive as well?  Could you maybe elaborate, or give another example?  Sorry, just not clicking for me...

Comment: The first derivative determines if the function is increasing or decreasing while the second derivative determines how it increases or decreases - in other words if it's convex or concave. Now, we consider the function $f(x,2)$, i.e. the $y$-coordinate is held fixed and look at this function as depending on one variable $x$. Can you see why $f(x,2)$ is convex near $x=3$?

Comment: No... I'm sorry, I'm still not seeing it...

Comment: Ok, note that $f(3,2)=15$ and going to the right we see that every line represents increase of $15$ in $f(x,2)$. But going to the right we see that these lines are lying closer and closer to each other meaning that we have a steeper and steeper increase in $f$.

Comment: So, are you saying that at y=2, as you increase x, the slope appears to be increasing, so that means f_xx is positive?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for being unclear. Just as $f_x$ being positive implies $f$ is increasing we have that $f_{xx}$ being positive implies that $f_x$ is increasing, i.e. the slope is increasing.

Comment: Alright, cool! Thanks for the help, and being patient with me!

Comment: "...not only does[the value of the curves,ie the different values of z shown by the numbers on the graph of the line]increase but it increases faster and faster (the lines of the contour plot get closer together when moving farther along f(x,2) ie for each small step you take in that same direction along f(x,2) the value of z increases by a lot more]" Does that help? My question would be in the f(3,y) direction. f_y(3,2)<0 is f_yy<0? It is decreasing at a faster rate...so........ and what about things like f_yx or f_xy?

Answer (score 1):

The $f_x$ tells if you will "hike" up or down  ($+$ or $-$) from your position, while $f_{xx}$ determines if you are "hiking" steeper or leveling off ($+$ or $-$). Since $f_x$ is moving "uphill" and doing so at a faster and faster rate (the lines are scrunching up) then we know $f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ are both positive.